# Can a 'type' be a single entity?

Tags: ontology

Can something be a 'type' and be a single entity, for example take a certain discipline, which can be split into multiple sub-disciplines, we often describe them as 'types' or 'kinds' of the discipline, is this a linguistic issue or an issue with viewing types and always needing a collection to fall under it?

For example if 'cat' is a type, it has multiples who fall under it, but there is not necessarily multiples that fall under 'Mechanical Engineering' despite it being referred to as a 'type of engineering'. Can a type be anything which is a subgroup of another thing or something which is a collection in a true sense.
Perhaps this is just a linguistic thing, but the question is interesting regardless, what can be a 'type'?

Perhaps my definition of type is mixed with that of 'category', where a type is any subdivision of something?

Comment: See the Realism vs Nominalism issue: are universal "real"? Are there abstract objects?

Comment: Maybe useful: [Types and Tokens](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/types-tokens/).